# javax.microedition.io.file does not exist in BlueJ

Tags: java-me

Trying j2me app development. I got a simple Hello to work, and a simple TextBox user as well. But when I tried to compile code for a file browser I got "javax.microedition.io.file does not exist".

The WTK according to the Sun website is supposed to include JSR75. And there's a camera demo .java file that uses it.

I've looked in various places (the WTK, BlueJ, even Netbeans) for menu options to turn it on. Nothing. And a search of this forum turned up exactly ONE message and it pertains to another IDE, and it seemed to work for him in BlueJ.

So what am I missing and how do I get it?

Answer (score 0):

In NetBeans, you go to Project Properties (right-click the project, and select Properties). Then click "Platform" and mark "File Connection and PIM Optional Packages 1.0".

Answer (score 0):

On a whim I did a search for JSR75 jar download and found a few zipped jar files that seemed to contain the file classes. I unzipped one of them and put it in the Libraries/Userlib directory of BlueJ; and now I seem to have the File... Classes. Reading and writing seem to work in the emulator.

I'll take another look at Netbeans when I get a chance.